# Fastest implementation for simplifying boolean expressions

Tags: performance-tuning

Suppose I wish to create a function to simplify boolean expressions. I do not wish to use the built-in rules Simplify or BooleanMinimize, but rather to create my own rules of simplification. I would like to ask you which is the fastest implementation we could create for such a function.

Initially, I tried, for instance:

```
SetAttributes[And, Orderless];
SetAttributes[Or, Orderless];
mysimplify[expression_] := expression //. {And[a_, Or[And[! a_, d__], b__], c___] :> And[a, Or[b], c], And[! a_, Or[And[a_, d__], b__], c___] :> And[! a, Or[b], c]};
```

However, for a complex expression, such as:

```
expr = ! A[3] && ! F[y[1], y[2], x[1]] && !H[y[1], y[3], x[3]] && ((A[1] && J[x[5]]) || (! A[6] && ! H[y[3], y[3], x[5]])) && ((A[2] && G[x[4]]) || (! A[5] && ! F[y[1], y[3], x[4]])) && ((A[3] && F[x[7, 1], x[8, 1], x[9, 1]]) || (A[4] && H[x[7, 1], x[8, 1], x[10, 1]])) && ((A[5] && F[x[7, 2, 1], x[8, 2, 1], x[9, 2, 1]]) || H[x[7, 2, 1], x[8, 2, 1], x[10, 2, 1]]) && ((A[6] && H[x[7, 2, 2], x[8, 2, 2], x[10, 2, 2]]) || (A[7] && F[x[7, 2, 2], x[8, 2, 2], x[9, 2, 2]])) && ((! A[1] && !J[x[2]]) || (! A[4] && ! H[y[1], y[2], x[2]])) && ((!A[2] && ! G[x[6]]) || (! A[7] && ! F[y[3], y[3], x[6]]));
```

the time needed to simplify the expression is almost 40s!

```
Timing[mysimplify[expr]]

{36.9219, A[4] && A[7] && F[x[7, 2, 2], x[8, 2, 2], x[9, 2, 2]] && H[x[7, 1], x[8, 1], x[10, 1]] &&  H[x[7, 2, 1], x[8, 2, 1], x[10, 2, 1]] && ! A[1] && ! A[2] && ! A[3] && ! A[5] && ! A[6] && ! F[y[1], y[2], x[1]] && !F[y[1], y[3], x[4]] && ! G[x[6]] && ! H[y[1], y[3], x[3]] && !H[y[3], y[3], x[5]] && ! J[x[2]]}
```

I would like to ask if there is possibly a very fast implementation for this case.

Comment: Are you sure that your code is copied as in your notebook? For me the code is pretty fast: It takes only a third of a millisecond --- but it also does nothing.

Comment: Dear @HenrikSchumacher I forgot to add the following lines: SetAttributes[And, Orderless];
SetAttributes[Or, Orderless];

Comment: "SetAttributes[And, Orderless];" Doing that is a sure way to break your system (!!!). Just don't do it.

Comment: Well, my first thought was: Why is `And` not `Orderless` in the first place? Then occurred to me that it is probably not `Orderless` in order to enable short-circuiting: This is illustrated by `And[Echo[1 == 0], Echo[1 == 1]]` vs. And[Echo[1 == 1], Echo[1 == 1]] . Anyways, I am not convinced that making `And` `Orderless` would break anything essential, but it may have a severe performance hit here and there...

Comment: Dear @HenrikSchumacher, if I do not use SetAttributes, my code doesn't work, unless I change the patterns, but the result in terms of efficiency is the same.